# Adding DateTime to List loses 12 hours

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have a date time:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
```

I format the time to the layout that I need. When I add the time to the List the time changes. E.g. 14:00 to 02:00.

```
List<DateTimeQty> timeList= new List<DateTimeQty>();
timeList.Add(new DateTimeQty(Convert.ToDateTime(time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))));
```

I try to then increment the hour but the result stays the same. e.g.

```
time.AddHours(1);
```

02:00 is going in and 02:00 is coming out not 03:00. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using string formatting and parsing is a rather slow and clumsy approach to truncate sub-seconds.  Instead, just use math.  `time.AddTicks(-time.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
time = time.AddHours(1);
```

That's what you need.

`time.AddHours(1)` just creates a **new** DateTime with one hour more. It does not add to the `time` variable.

Comment: To add to this, the reason it creates a new `DateTime` is because `DateTime` is a `struct` and not a `class`. Structs are different from classes in that structs are immutable, meaning once a struct object has been initialized its properties cannot be modified.

Comment: Structs are not immutable. You can create mutable structs. However, it's highly recommended to make structs immutable. And DateTime like all other (I'm guessing here) structs in the .NET Framework is immutable.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to use 24 hour formatting , change `hh` to `HH`:

```
timeList.Add(new DateTimeQty(Convert.ToDateTime(time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))));
```

Comment: Upvoted. I was naughty and asked two questions in one. Sadly can't pick both answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that custom format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` which causes the fail of parsing your DateTime. I wouldn't recommend using custom formats at all, instead, you should have a look at standard formats `"d", "D", "f", "F", "g", "G", "m", "o", "R", "s", "t", "T", "u", "U", "y"`. If you are in hurry, just pick "s" for instance.

More information on DateTime formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

As mentioned before, you need to assign your resulting value to initial one.

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
time = time.AddHours(1);
```

The reason for such behaviour is that [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) is an immutable structure which is a value type. So `time.AddHours(1)` allocates new instance of DateTime, but not changing the existing one named `time`.

I suggest you reading [this article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) to better differentiate value types from reference types.